# Onload Functions Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried several way to do run onload function , like

```
$(function(){
   // DOM Ready - do your stuff 
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // ...
});

jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
   // by passing the $ you can code using the $ alias for jQuery
   // ...
  });
})(jQuery);
```

But as soon as i load my website , on source code its not working , i am running following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("input[type='password']").after('<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="##############"></div>');
});
```

And in source code its looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() );
</script>
```

Chrome Console
[image]

HTML : 
[image]
I dont know whats going on why its not working .

Thanks

Comment: Put an  `alert("loaded");` inside the loading function to see if it really doesn't load!

Comment: share your html pls

Comment: Not working....

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() );` should be `$(document).ready(function(){ //code goes here });`

Comment: @MichaelCoker , Its already like that , the code changes to that once i load the code

Comment: HTML Updated @ Salih

Comment: @Daiyan show your register.php